# Как откатить версию ffmpeg на FreeBSD 13?

Tags: ffmpeg, freebsd

Есть медиасервера, которые пишут самописным скриптом с помощью ffmpeg видео с камер. Видеофайлы, записанные ffmpeg 4.2 по 15 мин, а на новой версии ffmpeg 4.4 - разной длины, иногда 15 мин, иногда меньше. Подскажите, как откатить версию ffmpeg до 4.2 на FreeBSD 13?

Comment: А можно нескромный вопрос - насколько меньше? Может, это наоборот пофиксили баг в новом ffmpeg? Может, выравнивание по ключевым кадрам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот пакет годичной давности. Можете поискать у себя в `/var/cache/pkg`. Иначе - получить дерево портов ревизии 539347 и скомпилировать порт `multimedia/ffmpeg`.